# Why ELB Health daemon not use local Timezone

Tags: nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Every 5 seconds /var/log/healthd/daemon.log write log that file not exist.
 FILE exist, but nginx name it with LOCAL timezone, daemon tried to use UTC timezone.
all timezones files changed to LA zone.

why daemon tried to search file with UTC timezone?

W, [2020-02-16T10:29:53.494828 #3644]  WARN -- : log file "/var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.2020-02-16-18" does not exist

Comment: [tag:amazon-elb] is not Elastic Beanstalk.  Is Beanstalk what your question is about?  That's just "EB."  ELB is Elastic Load Balancer.

Comment: yes. i mean about Elastic Beanstalk. will remove this tag